# Laradock - Localhost refused to connect on Windows 10 using Nginx

Tags: laravel, docker, laradock

I have setup a laradock app on my local machine. I have followed the instructions as provided:
http://laradock.io/

In addition to that as I am on Windows 10, and using  Docker toolbox, I have shared my folder with the laradock's workspace. That's working fine as I can see my app's folders inside the workspace when I run the following command

`docker-compose exec workspace bash`

I have also added a host entry inside my hosts file on windows.
`127.0.0.1 localhost`

But nothing works. I get a response 'localhost refused to connect'. Even css files inside public folder are not accessible

Answer (score -1):

You should checkout the `nginx/sites` folder inside your `laradock` folder. Check the root path inside `default.conf` - `root /var/www/public;` should correspond to where your project `/public` folder actually is inside `workspace`.

I personally use laradock for many projects and create multiple `.conf` files that correspond to my sites name like `myproject1.test` - `myproject1.conf` and my file structure is like that:

```
/laradock
/myproject1
/myproject2
```

hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 myproject1.test
127.0.0.1 myproject2.test
```

`myproject1.conf` inside `nginx/sites`:

```
...
server_name myproject1.test;
root /var/www/myproject1/public;
...
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I've been encountering the same issue, the question mentions difficulty specifically for Windows - I think part of the problem is that the Laradock Nginx config shows the `root` directory in Unix format